# Как получить данные для js из файла python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, html5

У меня есть html, в котором мне нужно проверить нажатие на кнопку и в js изменить значение массива, который передаётся из python файла. Вот код:

```html
<div class="w3-show-inline-block">
    <div class="w3-bar">
        <h4 class="w3-wide">Сортировать по:
        <button id="sort_complexity_ascending" class="w3-button w3-black">сложности от 1 до 5</button>
        <button id="sort_complexity_descending" class="w3-button w3-black">сложности от 5 до 1</button>
        <button id="sort_alphabet_ascending" class="w3-button w3-black">алфавиту от А до Я</button>
        <button id="sort_alphabet_descending" class="w3-button w3-black">алфавиту от Я до А</button></h4>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    sort_complexity_ascending.onclick = function() {
        var count = {{ count|safe }}
        var history = {{ history|safe }}
        var button1 = {{ button1|safe }}
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            history[i] = button1[i];
        }
    };
</script>
<script>
    sort_complexity_descending.onclick = function() {
        var count = {{ count|safe }}
        var history = {{ history|safe }}
        var button1 = {{ button2|safe }}
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            history[i] = button2[i];
        }
    };
</script>
<script>
    sort_alphabet_ascending.onclick = function() {
        var count = {{ count|safe }}
        var history = {{ history|safe }}
        var button1 = {{ button3|safe }}
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            history[i] = button3[i];
        }
    };
</script>
<script>
    sort_alphabet_descending.onclick = function() {
        var count = {{ count|safe }}
        var history = {{ history|safe }}
        var button1 = {{ button4|safe }}
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            history[i] = button4[i];
        }
    };
</script>
```

Подскажите в чём ошибка?

Comment: А для чего это всё?

Comment: Для сортировки данных на сайте.

Comment: Как этот  html получает данные с Python  скрипта?

Comment: Покажите traceback